# Import Google Spreadsheet into a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I'm trying to import the URL with a query of a Google Spreadsheet into another Google Spreadsheet. 
So on my webpage, I use a URL like this: https://docs.google.com/a/chiseledimages.com/spreadsheet/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select%20C,D,E,F,G,H,I%20where%20%28A%20contains%20301%29&key=0AuOQkU9HTNwVdG5
to create a table referencing the specified Doc and Selecting certain columns where Column A equals my client's account number, in this case, 301.

What I want to do is have another spreadsheet that will automatically fill with the data from that URL. I tired =importdata("https://docs.google.com/a/chiseledimages.com/spreadsheet/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select%20C,D,E,F,G,H,I%20where%20%28A%20contains%20301%29&key=0AuOQkU9HTNwVdG5")
but that just seemed to import HTML and not fill the sheet with data.  I want to be able to do this so that my client can have a Google Spreadsheet that is auto-filled with their data at all times, while not having direct access to the original spreadsheet with all my clients' data.

Comment: ---
So I was able to fill the new spreadsheet using =importxml
I add the URL for the query into cell A1.  Then used =importxml(A1,"//tr") to pull all the lines from the table.  
However to take this to the next level, I wonder if there's a way to pull data from a specific sheet and have that data editable on another sheet. Then have both sheets updating each other?  savvy?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I typically use ImportRange to pull data from one sheet to another.  http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=155183

Answer (score 0):

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URLOFTHESHEET"; "SHEET!A1")
```